# Where can I download Okta SAML Toolkit for Java Jar

Tags: java, saml, okta

I been searching all over the web for this Okta SAML Toolkit for Java jar. The instructions in the okta documentation [page](https://support.okta.com/help/Documentation/Knowledge_Article/24880412-Okta-SAML-Toolkit-for-Java) says to go [to](https://help.okta.com/en/prev/Content/Topics/Settings/Settings_Downloads.htm) however there is no download button on the page to get the Zip/Jar file. Can someone please tell me where I can download it from?

Comment: I dislike poorly designed websites; I couldn't find it either.

Comment: I wonder if you need to be logged in as a developer first, though (okta is not a free toolkit).

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Maybe I can help. If you happen to be using Spring Boot and want to use SAML with Okta, see https://developer.okta.com/blog/2017/03/16/spring-boot-saml.

Comment: @MattRaible I am trying to update the saml-toolkit jar in our project and I can't find it in the public maven repo. Also we are not using spring framework.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't published on Maven central. You can download it from your Okta Admin Console -> Settings -> Downloads

Comment: There is no button to download on that page that's the purpose of this question.

Comment: Interesting. Can you send me a screenshot (privately). Either way, you can try to access it directly https://{your-okta-admin-domain}/static/toolkits/Okta-SAMLToolkit-2.0.5.zip